# Make conda use environment packages over site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, conda

**In short:**

How can I force conda to use environment packages over site-packages.

**In detail:**

I'm running a python program in a conda environment. Lets give an example:

```
from rdkit import Chem

from rdkit.Chem.QED import qed
import torch

print(torch.__version__)
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('N=C(CCSCc1csc(N=C(N)N)n1)NS(N)(=O)=O')
print(qed(m))
```

Ok, simple enough. This program is importing two packages:

1. `RDKit` which is installed in the conda environment and
2. `pytorch` which is installed both in conda environment and one other location that is in `sys.path`. Note that `pytorch` version in these two locations are different.

When I run the program, it imports pytorch from the other location outside the conda environment. But this is an older version. How can I make python import `pytorch` package only from the conda environment packages.

---

Edits:
The output of `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` is:

```
['',
 '/USER_PATH/.conda/envs/Blade_env/lib/python36.zip',
 '/USER_PATH/.conda/envs/Blade_env/lib/python3.6',
 '/USER_PATH/.conda/envs/Blade_env/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/USER_PATH/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/USER_PATH/.conda/envs/Blade_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

The output of

```
print(torch.__file__)
print(Chem.__file__)
```

is

```
/USER_PATH/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py
/USER_PATH/.conda/envs/Blade_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/__init__.py
```

Comment: can you add the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)` ?

Comment: @cel Sure, Done.